# how to assign css class to jquery variables?

Tags: jquery, html, css

hello everyone i am new to css and jquery in my project iam using diffrent css classes based on some conditions loop.

```
if(get_node_details[i]['node_status'] == "ONLINE")
                        {
                            var panel_color = ".panel panel-primary";

                            if(get_node_details[i]['node_type'] == "SECONDARY")
                            {
                                var panel_color = ".panel panel-info";
                            }
                            else if(get_node_details[i]['node_type'] == "STAND_ALONE")
                            {
                                var panel_color = ".panel panel-success";
                            }
```

i am assigning css classes to javascript variables and i am writing dynamic phtml in the same page.

```
var text = "";
                                text = text + 
                                '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">\
                                    <div id="panel_id_'+node_index+'" class='+panel_color+'>\
</div>
```

but the class is not applying to panel depending upon the condition....please help me with this

Comment: Classes _in HTML_ don't have leading dots, you're mixing in CSS selector syntax here.

Comment: remove `.` i.e. `var panel_color = "panel panel-primary";`

Comment: `if`, `else if` then `else`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the class name to variable like that

```
var className = "active";
$("#divId").addClass(className);
```

Here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32vbLvy6/1/) link

Answer (score 0):

```
       I have updated your code please check.   
           if(get_node_details[i]['node_status'] == "ONLINE")
                    {
                        var panel_color = ".panel panel-primary";

                        if(get_node_details[i]['node_type'] == "SECONDARY")
                        {
                            panel_color = ".panel panel-info";
                        }
                        else if(get_node_details[i]['node_type'] == "STAND_ALONE")
                        {
                            panel_color = ".panel panel-success";
                        }
                       $("#divId").addClass(panel_color);
                    }
```